# SQL Query to iterate within XML Nodes to check for a value and return the record

Tags: sql, xml, db2, xquery-sql

One of my database table has multiple records. In each record there is a column which stores the XML of following type . I need to write a query which should fetch the records wherein inside the  parent node ,if any of the sub  node contains only the value 0 entirely. In this example, the fourth  node contains all 0. This satisfies the condition and the record must be fetched. May I know how to write this condition in SQL to fetch like this?

Note : The  parent node may contain multiple  sub nodes.

XML:

```
        <videoDetails>
            <video>
                <V1>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V1>
                <V2>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V2>
                <V3>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V3>
                <V4>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V4>
                <V5>
                    <display>1</display>
                </V5>
            </video>
            <video>                 
                <V1>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V1>
                <V2>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V2>
                <V3>
                    <display>1</display>
                </V3>
                <V4>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V4>
                <V5>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V5>
            </video>
            <video>                 
                <V1>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V1>
                <V2>
                    <display>1</display>
                </V2>
                <V3>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V3>
                <V4>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V4>
                <V5>
                    <display>1</display>
                </V5>
            </video>
            <video>                 
                <V1>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V1>
                <V2>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V2>
                <V3>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V3>
                <V4>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V4>
                <V5>
                    <display>0</display>
                </V5>
            </video>
        </videoDetails>
```

I tried to use something like NOT xmlexists('$N/../../../videoDetails/video[1]/*[display=1]' passing USER_VIDEO_XML as "N") . This works only when the XML contains one  node which has all 0 and doesn't work with multiple  nodes.

Request your valuable inputs.

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: your xPath is forcing it it look at the 1st <video> node only.  `.../video[1]...`.  that [1] forces it to ignore all the others. Have you tried without specifying the array position. `'$N/../../../videoDetails/video/*[display=1]'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM MY_TAB T
WHERE XMLCAST(XMLQUERY
(
'
let $d :=
for $v in $doc/videoDetails/video
  return fn:exists($v/*[display != 0])
return fn:exists($d[. = fn:false()])
' PASSING T.DOC AS "doc" 
) AS INT) = 1
```

The `for` loop iterates all `video` sub-nodes, and returns the following sequence in $d for your given example:
`(true, true, true, false)`
4 `video` sub-nodes. The first 3 of them contain `display !=0`, but the 4-th doesn't.
The outer `return` clause returns true, if the sequence above contains the `false` value.
You may play with sample data checking the result at the following [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=f4512d2ce9ca5f718090b1fc527559a6) link.